# lattice::bwplot and groups parameter

Tags: r, lattice

Here is a code example (based on random data):

```
lattice::bwplot(runif(1000) ~ cut(runif(1000), c(0,0.3,0.6,1)) | as.factor(c(1,2,3)), 
                groups = sample(1:2, 1000, replace = TRUE), auto.key = TRUE)
```

The output:

[image]

I am expecting to get 6 boxplots in each panel due to `groups`, but I only get 3. At the top is the legend: one sees two colors representing 2 groups but you don't see these in the pannels.

How can I get 6 boxplots in each panel, one for each interval *and* for each group in the correct color?

Answer (score 4):

The `groups` argument in `bwplot()` doesn't do much other than affect the key unfortunately. I wrote a modified `bwplot()` in my **tactile** package.

Try:

```
tactile::bwplot2(runif(1000) ~ cut(runif(1000), c(0,0.3,0.6,1)) | as.factor(c(1,2,3)), 
                 groups = sample(1:2, 1000, replace = TRUE), auto.key = TRUE)
```

[image]